# JBoss management via SSL

Tags: eclipse, ssl, jboss, command-line-interface, jboss-tools

I have a problem with my JBoss AS 7.1.1 after I configured it to use ssl for the management interface.

I followed [this guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SecuringAdministrationConsoleWithHttps) to secure the admin console. This worked.

But now I realized that the native management interface does not work anymore.
When I start my JBoss in Eclipse via the JBoss Tools I get lots of these error messages:

```
 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "myhost:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

I have the following configuration in the `standalone.xml`:

```
 <management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="my.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" password="xxPASSxx"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
        ...
    </security-realms>
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
        </native-interface>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding https="management-https"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
</management>

<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    ...
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply eclipse with `-vmargs` that point to your truststore. For example:

`C:\Eclipse\DevStudio64Bit\studio\jbdevstudio.exe -vmargs "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/apps/java/keystore/localhost.jks"`

This will allow eclipse to pass a valid cert to the server for management purposes.